# Travelling to USA - from UK on ESTA (already issued - without travel date details)

Tags: usa, passports, uk-citizens, esta

I have a valid ESTA issued recently (I did not have travel dates at the time), with flights now booked to US from UK on June 18th 2013, with a return date of July 6th 2013.

My passport is due to expire on January 9th 2014.

Does this fall within the 'approved' expiration date for ESTA approved countries, or is there a formula used by US Border Control to calculate '6 months' which bring me up short on the validity for my passport for my departure due on July 6th 2013?

Comment: My carrier (Virgin) via their web-tool is indicating my documentation (ie passport) may not be 'sufficient' to ensure entry to USA. I think they may be using the '6 month rule' applicable to non VWP countries such as the UK.

Comment: My question is - how do I determine with my carrier that they will accept me on the flight. I don't think there is an issue with entry through US CBP, but not sure if they have a different way of calculating the expiration period? Any input would be appreciated. I have been trawling the web for hours!!

Comment: The answer in the linked question provides this information.  Your ESTA is valid until your passport expiration.  So I am not sure what is your concern and how Virgin figures into this

Comment: @Karlson suspect his concern is not with CBP (ESTA) - it's with his carrier -Virgin. As he said, their tool for checking this claims his passport won't be valid, despite what we know.

Comment: Thank you Mark, your interpretation is correct. Virgin are saying that my documentation (ie my passport) is not valid for travel. I think this is a mis-interpretation of the regulations on their part. I have checked the UK Foreign Office & Commonwealth web site, and also the Carrier Information Guide issued by US CBP. Both say passport only needs to be valid for the duration of stay. Virgin say differently.

Comment: Then the question should probably be directed at Virgin since the assumption on their part is likely that you're purchasing tickets to obtain ESTA rather then you already having one.  And the question of possibility of entry is up to the border control rather then an airline.